# How to create custom widget via Install?

Tags: magento2, php, widget, install-script, widget-instance

I need to create widget category link via Upgrade. How to do this?

Comment: Creating a widget cannot be done in setup files, however you can create module for it and when it installs widget will appear in admin. Please let me know if you want code for that.

Comment: it would be great! Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom widget can not be created alone with a Install or Upgrade script. You need to create a module for it.

Below are the simple steps to create a widget via a module:

> 1. Create app/code/Stack/CustomWidget/registration.php and paste below code in it:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Stack_CustomWidget',
    __DIR__
);
```

> 2. Create app/code/Stack/CustomWidget/module.xml and paste below code in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Stack_CustomWidget" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

> 3. Next, you’ll need to create a widget.xml configuration file under  app/code/Stack/CustomWidget/etc/ folder with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<widgets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Widget:etc/widget.xsd">
    <widget class="Stack\CustomWidget\Block\Widget\Samplewidget" id="stack_customwidget_samplewidget">
        <label>Stack Sample Widget</label>
        <description></description>
        <parameters>
             <parameter name="widgettitle" sort_order="10" visible="true" xsi:type="text">
                 <label>Title</label>
             </parameter>
             <parameter name="widgetcontent" sort_order="20" visible="true" xsi:type="textarea">
                 <label>Content</label>
             </parameter>
        </parameters>
    </widget>
</widgets>
```

In the `<widget>` tag, I have declared a block class, Stack\CustomWidget\Block\Widget\Samplewidget that instructs our widget to use the particular template.

> 4. Now create **Samplewidget.php** in **`app/code/Stack/CustomWidget/Block/Widget/`** directory with the following code:

```
<?php
namespace Stack\CustomWidget\Block\Widget;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface;

class Samplewidget extends Template implements BlockInterface
{
    protected $_template = "widget/samplewidget.phtml";
}
```

> 5. Finally, create a widget template file **samplewidget.phtml** in **app/code/Stack/CustomWidget/view/frontend/templates/widget** with the following code:

```
<?php if($block->getData('widgettitle')): ?>
            <h2 class='stack-title'><?php echo $block->getData('widgettitle'); ?></h2>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($block->getData('widgetcontent')): ?>
            <h2 class='stack-content'><?php echo $block->getData('widgetcontent'); ?></h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Here, as you can see that I have picked up the value from fields by calling $block->getData('parameter'); where the parameters are widgettitle and widgetcontent.

Now, login to your Magento 2 Admin panel and navigate to Content > Pages to see the widget in action.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a pretty good tutorial for creating a widget in custom module by inchoo [here](https://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-custom-widget/).

[Here](https://github.com/ivanmiskic/magento2_custom_widget) is also same module on github so you can customise it as your need.

Please let me know if have any confusion.

Comment: i should to do my own category link widget, how to do this?
need create 4 category link widgets for different blocks